Understand createContext hook
I am new to react and I am a little bit lost with createContext hook.
I created a Api component to fetch data from my backend
export interface List{
    id?: string,
    sku?: string,
    name?: string,
    description?: string,
    unit_price?: number,
    image_url?: string,
    active?: boolean,
    units_in_stock?: number,
    date_created?: Date,
    last_updated?: Date,
    category?:number
}
export const Context = createContext<List[]>([])
 function Api() {

    const [product, setProduct] = useState<List[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async ()=>{

        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/djassa/products/')
            setProduct(response.data)
            
            
        } 
        
        catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch products", error)     
        }
      }

      fetchData()
    }, [])
    

  return (
    <>
        < Context.Provider value={product} >
            <Home />
        </Context.Provider>

    </>
  )
}

export default Api


Then I wanted to display some of the data into Home Component.
function Home(){

    const data = useContext(Context)
   console.log(data);
   
    

    return(   
         <>
        {data.map((product) => (
          <p key={product.id}>{product.name}</p> 
        ))}
        <p>You just entered home.</p>
      </>)
}

export default Home

The problem is when I tried to rend home, it does not work
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'
import Home from './assets/component/Home';
import Api from './assets/component/Api';



function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Home />

    </>
  )
}

export default App


However, when I add Api component in place of Home component in my App component. it seams to work.
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'
import Home from './assets/component/Home';
import Api from './assets/component/Api';



function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Api />

    </>
  )
}

export default App



createContext has a single parameter which is the default value of the context when no provider can be found up the component tree. When you call useContext react will look up the component tree to see if it can find a provider of the correct type (it will take the first one it finds going back up the tree). If it can't find a provider you get the default value when the context was created (an empty array in this case). Api wraps home with a context provider, just using Home there is no context provider above it in the tree.

FYI createContext() is not a hook.

@JacobSmit  So basically, the only way to render data from other component wrapped by Api is by using Api component?

When you render Home component alone there is not any Context context provider being rendered above it in the ReactTree so the default context value is accessed, e.g. the empty array.
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Home /> // ??? where's the context? ‍♂️
    </>
  )
}

In the second example where you instead render Api, this works because Home is rendered as a direct child of the Context.Provider component and can thus access the provided context value.
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Api /> // <-- renders the context provider
    </>
  )
}

function Api() {
  ...
    

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={product}> // <-- provides the context
      <Home /> // <-- can access context 
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

A common pattern for context providers is to wrap and render their children prop.
Example:
function Api({ children }) {
  ...
    

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={product}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

Which allows you to render context consumers elsewhere in the sub-ReactTree.
function App() {
  return (
    <Api>
      ...
      <Home />
      ...
    </Api>
  );
}


Oh I see now. Thank You. `I guess I thought I can use Home anywhere as long as it was wrapped by Api.

@baoule_sama That would/could work, but then you'd want to be cautious if rendering multiple Home components or if other components needed the Context, rendering multiple Api components means each has its own state and provided context value, there's not automagical state sharing. Well, this is kind of what the Context Provider is for, you render one and any component rendered below it can access the shared provided context value.

Don't forget to supply the context for the <Home /> component -
function App() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={...}>
      <Home />
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

new for React 19
In React 19, you can render <Context> as a provider instead of <Context.Provider> -
function App() {
  return (
    <Context value={...}>
      <Home />
    </Context>
  )
}

New context providers can use <Context> and React team will be publishing a codemod to convert existing providers. In future versions <Context.Provider> will be deprecated.
